# jQuery: enable element on radio check

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery function isnt enabling my disabled submit button?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      if ($("#lawfulBasis").prop("checked")) {
         $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);   
       alert('Button Clicked');           
      };    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>
<input id="lawfulBasis" type="radio" value="3" /> I give consent for you to store my data for the purposes of marketing, to contact me about products and services via email and telephone*
<p>
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled/>
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question I think a check box might be a better UX choice so the user can withdraw their consent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you only read the state of the radio control in the document.ready handler, ie. when the page loads not when the user changes its state.

To fix this attach a `change` event handler to the radio and set the `disabled` state of the button based on that.

Finally, note that you should be using a checkbox for this, not a radio. The reason is that the radio cannot be deselected once selected for the first time.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#lawfulBasis").on('change', e => {
    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', !e.target.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input id="lawfulBasis" type="checkbox" value="3" /> 
  I give consent for you to store my data for the purposes of marketing, to contact me about products and services via email and telephone*
</label>
<p>
  <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did think about writing this up in jQuery but really it's just as easy to use vanilla js. Your problem was that you're checking all this when the docuemnt loads, and not when the button is pressed.

```js
document.getElementById("lawfulBasis").addEventListener("change", () => {
  const radio = document.getElementById("lawfulBasis");
  if (radio.checked) {
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="lawfulBasis" type="radio" value="3" /> I give consent for you to store my data for the purposes of marketing, to contact me about products and services via email and telephone*
<p>
  <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled/>
</p>
```

Comment: Good but you are not considering users who might check the button with their keyboard. `onchanged` is the event you should listen for.

Comment: @schwaber I've updated it to reflect that - for the record, I'm not really thinking about users at all for an answer like this - the answer is to solve one small, specific technical problem, and issues such as accessibility are left for the question's author to to solve

Comment: Thanks. That is much better. But it is not really an accesibility question. The point is that an `onclick` solution focuses the method of input instead of the state of the control and thereby asumes the use of a mouse and dismisses all other subsets of usecases without good reason.

Comment: That's what I call accessibility @schwaber - it's about allowing users to interact with a site in the method which they choose. Still, the point stands, the difference is not relevant to issue at hand in the original question

Comment: It is equivalent to a bodyguard letting someone stab a person because he has only been instructed to look out for people trying to shoot him. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need an eventlistner: `$('#lawfulBasis').change()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lawfulBasis').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);   
      alert('Button Clicked');           
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>
<input id="lawfulBasis" type="radio" value="3" /> I give consent for you to store my data for the purposes of marketing, to contact me about products and services via email and telephone*
<p>
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled/>
</p>

</body>

</html>
```